# A conversão falhou ao converter o valor varchar 'Não' para o tipo de dados tinyint

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, microsoft-excel

Estou a tentar resolver um erro penso eu de conversão de uma variável criada por mim para armazenar dados que estão numa folha de Excel.

O erro acontece quando tento inserir o dado que esta nessa variável no `SQL Server`, ou seja na (query).

código:

declaração da variável:

```
string valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal = "";
```

código de busca da informação:

```
case 47://coluna 21

if (((WS.Cells[linha, Contcoluna] as Excel.Range).Value) != null)
{
    valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal = Convert.ToString((WS.Cells[linha, Contcoluna] as Excel.Range).Value);  
}
continue;
```

código de inserção no sql server:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT tabela_sacc (Morada_Fiscal_Igual_a_Morada_Local) VALUES ('" + valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal.ToString() + "')";

connection.Open();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
valgrupo = null;
```

Comment: Realmente não é possível converte um **não** ou um **sim** para um tinyint, não existe função para isso, o que pode ser feito é um case ou uma função que faça isso. em todo caso sua pergunta não esta clara suficiente para elabora uma boa resposta.

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, boa tarde

se o valor que você está tentando inserir for um inteiro, tenta tira as aspas simples do seu código

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT tabela_sacc (Morada_Fiscal_Igual_a_Morada_Local) VALUES (" + valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal + ")";
```

o recomenando seria vc utilizar o sqlparameter https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx aonde você define qual o tipo da tabela

espero ter ajudado

Comment: boa tarde, não é um inteiro é uma string mais concretamente a palavra (não).

Comment: qual o tipo da coluna Morada_Fiscal_Igual_a_Morada_Local e qual o valor que está em valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal  pelo o que eu estou vendo é uma conversão pra boleano, não seria o caso ? alguams pessoas utilizam o tipo tinyint para representar o boolean no sql server em vez do tipo Bit, e pelo visto seu dado está retonado a palavra Não, se for o caso vc terá de fazer um if: valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal =="Não"?0:1;

Comment: Desde já quero agradecer pela sua ajuda , sou muito novo em programação e como tal estou a ter dificuldade em perceber o que quer que eu faça no if? A a variavel valmoradafiscaligualmoradaloca vai conter a palavra Não isso é correto. Mas o objetivo nao é converter para boleano , mas sim string

Comment: Será que é isto? 
                        string variavelauxiliar = "";
                        if (variavelauxiliar == null)
                        {
                            valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal = variavelauxiliar;
                        } cmd.CommandText = " INSERT tabela_sacc (Morada_Fiscal_Igual_a_Morada_Local) VALUES ('" + variavelauxiliar + "')";

Comment: Não funcionou estou a inserir o valor nulo não o conteúdo da variável valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal

Comment: mas ai é que você pode está se enganado, você não pode converter a palavra Não para string se o tipo no seu banco de dados não for varchar ou nvarchar, a sua conversão dentro da query sql tem de ser para um tipo semelhante ao do banco de dados, por isto. No caso ele parece ser um tinyint que aceita valores de 0 a 255 diferent de um bit que só aceita 0 e 1.

Comment: Estou a perceber mas a minha coluna na base de dados aceita varchar(50) , não deve ser por causa disso. Agradeço se ma ajuda se esta a ser muito util!

Comment: @DiogoGomes, você comentou que sua coluna é `varchar(50)`, mas deve ter algo incorreto, porque a mensagem de erro é de conversão para `tinyint`, pode confirmar o tipo correto do campo **Morada_Fiscal_Igual_a_Morada_Local** no banco?

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, tente fazer seu código utilizando sql parameter, segue exemplo

```
 var serverName = "LAPTOP-EVEJOG4C";
        var databaseName = "MyDatabase";
        var dataString = "Não";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection($"Server={serverName};Database={databaseName};Trusted_Connection=True;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "insert Example01 (DadoTinyInt) values (@DadoTinyInt)";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DadoTinyInt", System.Data.SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value =
                    dataString == "Não" ? 0 : 1;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Eu estou a perceber onde quer chegar mas eu não  posso fazer da sua maneira sugerida,pois a variável  valmoradafiscaligualmoradalocal pode ser outra string qualquer por exmplo (sim ou talvez) Grato pela compreensão.

Comment: Então em vez de declarar ela como tinyint declare como nvarchar 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dado", System.Data.SqlDbType.Nvarchar, 50).Value = seu valor

Comment: Vou continuar a ter o mesmo problema, porque o valor vai ser diferente se eu usar outra sheet do excel ! eu tenho de fazer isto para outras 172 colunas não é viável faze-lo dessa maneira por si sugerida.agradeço a disponibilidade